# How to implement equals() for related subtypes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, equality

I'm trying to implement a class tree of related types (for example, e.g AST nodes) with a common abstract superclass. I'm trying to implement `equals()` on the subnodes so that different sub types are indeed different, but two like types can do a more introspective computation of equality. I've tried this:

```
abstract class Something {
    abstract fun equals(other:Something) : Boolean 
}

class Foo(val value:Int):Something() {
    override fun equals(other:Something) : Boolean {
        return (other as Foo).value == value
    }
}

class Bar(val value:Int):Something() {
    override fun equals(other:Something) : Boolean {
        return (other as Bar).value == value
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val foo1:Something = Foo(1)  // if i don't type these as the abstract type
    val foo2:Something = Foo(1)  // then I it won't even let me check
    val bar1:Something = Bar(42) // if bar1 == foo1, because they're inferred
    val bar2:Something = Bar(42) // as different types
    println("foo1 == foo2 ${foo1 == foo2}") // should print true
    println("bar1 == bar2 ${bar1 == bar2}") // should print true
    println("foo1 == bar1 ${foo1 == bar2}") // should print false
}
```

Unfortunately, all of the `println`'s just show false though. What am I doing wrong?wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `==` calls the `Object`'s `equals(Any?)` method, not your overload. So you need to have `override operator fun equals(other: Any?)` everywhere.
2. Your implementations will throw exception instead of returning `false` for wrong types, that's bad. Instead you need

   ```
   // in Foo
   override fun equals(other: Any?) : Boolean = when (other) {
       is Foo -> other.value == value
       else -> false
   }
   ```

Comment: side question.. is there a reason to prefer the when expression over just `other is Foo && other.value == value` ? (I was surprised this actually works; I keep forgetting the "once you test it, we can make assumptions about it bit that the compiler is willing to do as side effects)

Comment: No, I like that version better, I just didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `==` to work properly, You have to override `operator fun equals(other: Any?) : Boolean`.

If you want to explicitly require implementation in subclasses so you don't forget about it, you can mark it as `abstract` in the superclass:

```
abstract class Something {
    abstract override operator fun equals(other: Any?) : Boolean
}

class Foo(val value:Int):Something() {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return (other as Foo).value == value
    }
}

class Bar(val value:Int):Something() {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return (other as Bar).value == value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use syntax `foo1 == foo2` Kotlin calls function:

```
open operator fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean
```

of class `Any` and not your custom equals implementation.

You need to use syntax `foo1.equals(foo2)` to do what you want. Also, like Alexey Romanov pointed in his answer, you cannot cast `Foo` to `Bar` and vice versa, you need to do:

```
override fun equals(other:Something) : Boolean {
        return when(other) {
         is Foo -> other.value == value
         is Bar -> other.value == value
         else false
        }
    }
```

in both `Foo` and `Bar` classes.